# Invalid JSON primitive when deserializing

Tags: c#, json

Alright, so having this issue when I try to run my application:

> Invalid JSON primitive: .

```
public static void ReloadConfig()
{
    if (!File.Exists("config.cfg"))
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.Append("{\r\n");
        sb.Append("\"Admins\":[76561198214617172],\r\n");
        sb.Append("\"Chatty\":false,\r\n");
        sb.Append("}");

        File.WriteAllText("config.cfg", sb.ToString());
    }
    try
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        config = jss.Deserialize<Roles>(File.ReadAllText("config.cfg"));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        Console.ReadKey();
        ReloadConfig();
    }
}
```

And this is how the config looks like when it's generated:

```
{
"Admins":[76561198214617172],
"Chatty":false,
}
```

As from my error message I would assume it says I have a space in my config, but I do not have that.

And if that matters I use `System.Web.Script.Serialization`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have an errant comma in your output after `false`:

```
{
"Admins":[76561198214617172],
"Chatty":false,
}
```

Should be:

```
{
"Admins":[76561198214617172],
"Chatty":false
}
```

Comment: Interesting it should error on that since having that extra comma should not be invalid.

Comment: @garryp That comma **is** invalid, try parsing it an any Json tool.

Comment: That did solve my problem, I would assume a extra comma would not cause so much drama. Yet I am new to json, thanks!

Comment: @garryp Just because the browser copes with the additional comma doesn't mean it's right. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/eLmgop7x/ :)

Comment: @garryp A particular implementation may choose to be more tolerant than required, but it doesn't have to. The [specification](http://www.json.org/) clearly states that a comma in a JSON object must be followed by a key-value pair.

Comment: I'm surprised. I'd have expected JSON to support something that is part of the Javascript language that it is based on http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.1.5

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove the comma after false:

```
{
"Admins":[76561198214617172],
"Chatty":false
}
```

I used [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate your JSON, there are many other online JSON validators.